# jQuery plugin missing ; before statement (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, syntax-error

I'm getting

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement }) (jQuery);

in the code below. I'm trying to make a jQuery plugin and I don't see what's wrong here:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.hideElement = function(options) {
  options = $.extend({}, $.fn.hideElement.defaults, options);

  return this.each(function(){
    var wrapping = $(this).css('white-space');
    $(this).css({'white-space':'nowrap'})
      .animate(options.toggling,1000, function(){
        $('<p>').text('»')
          .insertAfter($(this))
          .click(function(){
             $(this).prev()
             .animate(options.toggling,1000)
             .css({'white-space':wrapping})
             .next().remove();
      });
    });  
  });
  $.fn.hideElement.defaults = {
    'toggling':'width',
  }
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: `$.fn.hideElement = function(options) {` isn't closed. Add another `}` before `}) (jQuery);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brace tabs are unbalanced so not that easy to spot.

`$.fn.hideElement = function(options) {` isn't closed.

Add another `}` before `}) (jQuery);`

Comment: Totally missed that when I added the closure! Thanks!